# Equivalent definitions of Centerpoint

Tags: vector-spaces, discrete-geometry

In Jiri Matousek's book - "Lectures on Discrete Geometry", he defines centerpoint as:

**1.4.1 Definition (Centerpoint).** Let $X$ be an $n$-point set in $\mathbb R^d$. A point $x \in \mathbb R^d$ is called a centerpoint if each closed half-space containing $x$ contains at least $\frac{n}{d+1}$ points of $X$.

However, after some explanation, when he goes on to prove the *Centerpoint Theorem*, he says this:

First we note an *equivalent definition of centerpoint:*

$x$ is a centerpoint of $X$ if and only if it lies in each open half-space $\gamma$ such that $|X \cap \gamma| > \frac{d}{d+1}n$.

Can anyone explain to me how these two are definitions equivalent? Also, why does $\frac{n}{d+1}$ change to $\frac{nd}{d+1}$, when the characterization of half-spaces changes from closed to open?

Also, is there any significance of why in the first definition, only **if** is used, and in the second (alternate) definition **if and only if** is used? Does it mean that $\leftarrow$ side of first definition is not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when making a definition *if* and *if, and only if* are often used interchangeably.

For the rest of the question, let **D1** be the first definition, and let **D2** be the second one.

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfy **D1**. Take an open half-space $\gamma$ such that $|X\cap\gamma| > \tfrac{dn}{d+1}$. Then the complement $\gamma^c$ is closed and contains at most $n - \tfrac{dn}{d+1} = \frac{n}{d+1}$ points, and thus cannot contain $x$. It follows that $x\in\gamma$, so that $x$ satisfies **D2**.

Conversely, if $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies **D2**, let $\delta$ be a closed half-space containing $x$. Its complement $\delta^c$ is open and doesn't contain $x$, and thus we have $|X\cap\delta^c|\le \tfrac{dn}{d+1}$, so that $\delta$ must contain at least $\tfrac{n}{d+1}$ points of $X$. Therefore, $x$ satisfies **D1**.

As it is now evident from the proof of the equivalence, the switch between $\tfrac{n}{d+1}$ and $\tfrac{dn}{d+1}$ is given by taking the complement.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. :-)